# Exclude source/class file from deployment only

Tags: java, maven, deployment, compilation

I'm working on a JavaFX project and there is a framework behind the scenes which handles CDI to inject a context. The problem is that the GUI is part of a bigger application and I want to be able to test it without the need to start the whole application every time. For this, I needed to update a file which is included in a dependency. I copied it to my workspace and added system properties that I can set in my launcher to fake some needed data. Until the dependency is updated to include this behavior, I need to keep the patched class in my project. The problem is, it should not be released.

So basically I want to exclude a java file from deployment but not from compilation so I can use it locally in my project.

I already tried these things:

- maven-compiler-plugin: via exclusion I managed to get rid of the file but then it won't compile at all which means that I can't use its functionality in my project
- copy the file to src/test/java instead - the file is not visible from the JavaFX form in the main project
- maven-assembly-plugin: can't exactly get this to work the way I want it

Did I miss something or is there a way to achieve this with the assembly plugin without interrupting normal deployment?